# Ant javac task can't access class

Tags: java, ant

When running my ant build file I get the following message

```
-build-middleware-securitymanager:
     [echo] -> httpbean.securitymanager
     [echo] -> httpbean.securitymanager.config
     [echo] -> httpbean.securitymanager.context
     [echo] -> httpbean.securitymanager.login
     [echo] -> C:\eclipse\current\RunImported
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to C:\eclipse\current\new\classes
    [javac] C:\eclipse\current\httpbean\securitymanager\login\integration\bellsouth\LoginUserWS.java:192: cannot access ServiceException
    [javac] file ServiceException.class not found
    [javac]             final LoginInfo info = _login.login(user, clrpasswd, _token);
    [javac]                                                ^
```

Having checked my build file it's referring to the following section

```
    <echo message="-> httpbean.securitymanager.login" />
    <echo message="-> ${run-imported}" />
    <javac  includeantruntime="${ant8compat}" debug="${debug}" srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}" includes="httpbean/securitymanager/login/**/*.java" encoding="UTF-8">
        <exclude name="**/*_UnitTest.java" />
        <classpath>
            <path refid="Axis" />
            <path refid="commons-logging" />
            <path refid="shark-1.1" />
            <path refid="log4j" />
        </classpath>
    </javac>
```

The ServiceException class is part of the javax.xml.rpc package which is in the jaxrpc.jar in the shark-1.1 directory, shark-1.1 reference is

```
  <path id="shark-1.1">
    <fileset dir="${run-imported}/shark-1.1">
      <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
  </path>
```

Having checked the `${run-imported}/shark-1.1` directory I can quite clearly see the correct jar file sitting there!

I have tried adding a pathelement tag to the classpath part of the javac task to point directly to the jar file where the missing class lives but this also doesn't work.

EDIT:

The import is

```
import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;
```

And the jar is structured like so, ServiceException highlighted

[image: JAR directory structure]

Comment: In which jar file / `path id` is `ServiceException` present?

Comment: It's in jaxrpc.jar which is in the shark-1.1 path id, see the snippet above

Comment: Is the jar file directly under the directory `${run-imported}/shark-1.1`? I hope it is not inside a nested directory like `${run-imported}/shark-1.1/lib/shark-1.1.jar`?

Comment: nope it's directly underneath it

Comment: run ant in debug mode (-v), this will print the classpath for javac and you can verify that all jars are correctly in there.

Comment: @oers useful thanks, running that does indeed show that the correct jar is on the classpath so now I'm stumped!

Comment: are you 100% sure that the Exception is in that jar? according to findjar.com the fitting jar is jaxrpc-api.jar

Comment: I am indeed I've opened up the jar file in winzip and can see the .class staring me in the face

Comment: @oers sometimes it's repackaged inside other WS libraries, it's likely that the Axis reference contains one too. Actually, that may somehow be the source of the problem.

Comment: @Viruzzo I did think that because Axis does have a reference to the class, so I removed the Axis reference but it's still the same.

Comment: could you please add the following infos? source of the class in question(maybe only the imports, relevant parts) and the content of the jar(directory/file) structure. Something is wrong and it is hard to tell what it is :D

Comment: everything looks fine, it should totally work. no idea left :D

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure ServiceException is in the default package? Unlikely.
It should be something like "com.acme.bfo.cyberdyne.ServiceException".
Use

```
jar tf shark-1.1.jar | find "ServiceException"
```

to see the package.